# Fact about Integrally closed domains.

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be an integral domain. Then $\forall m$ where $m$ is maximal ideal in $A$,$\; A_{m}$ is integrally closed$\implies$ $A$ is integrally closed.

This fact is proved in Atiyah-MacDonald in a different way. I am trying to prove it in the following way and hoping to complete it:

The field of fractions of $A_{m}$ is same as the field of fractions of $A, K_{A}.\;$Then we want to prove that $a/b \in K_{A}$ is integral over $A\implies a/b\in A.\;$ Now, $a/b$ satisfies some monic polynomial over $A$ means it satisfies some monic polynomial over $A_{m}, \forall m.\;$ Hence, $a/b$ is integral over $A_{m},\forall m.\;$ Now I just have to prove that $b\notin m,\forall m.$ Suppose, $b\in m$ for some maximal ideal $m$. Then $a\in m.$

After that I'm stuck. Thanks in advance!

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119566/a-is-integrally-closed-if-and-only-if-a-p-is-integrally-closed-for-all-maxim?rq=1) may be helpful.

Comment: @Krish Thanks a lot! Exactly what I needed.