# normal noetherian schemes admit a connected affine open cover

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm recently working on normal schemes and locally factorial schemes. The following is a result I need, which I believe is true, but I don't know how to prove it.

Let $X$ be a noetherian normal scheme. Prove that for each $x\in X$ and an open neighborhood $V$, we can find an affine open neighborhood $U = \operatorname{Spec} A\subseteq V$ such that $A$ is a normal domain. In other words, we can find an affine open cover $\{U_i\}$ such that $\Gamma(U_i,\mathcal{O}_X)$ are normal domains.

Recall that $X$ is a normal scheme if all of its local rings are normal domains. Clearly $A$ is normal as $A_\mathfrak{p}$ is normal domain for each prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$. So, it remains to prove $A$ can be chosen as a domain. But I still don't know how to prove this. I've known that if $U\subseteq X$ is a connected open subset, then $\Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is a normal domain. So, one possible way is to find a connected affine open $U$. Seems that this is highly possible, even might be trivial, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119566/a-is-integrally-closed-if-and-only-if-a-p-is-integrally-closed-for-all-maxim

Comment: This is not what I want, I've known $A$ is normal from some comm algebra result. What I need to prove is $A$ is an integral domain.

Comment: This is Lemma 28.7.5 (Tag 0357) in the stacks project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lemma in the stacks project mentioned in the comments does it but here's another way to see this quickly:

Take an affine open $ U = \operatorname{Spec} A $ containing $ x $. Since $ X $ is Noetherian, $ U $ has finitely many connected components so let $ V $ be the one containing $ x $. Since $ V $ is a connected component, note that $ V $ is both open and closed in $ U $ therefore the open immersion $ j : V \rightarrow U $ is also a closed immersion. (Checking that $ \mathcal{O}_U \rightarrow j_* \mathcal{O}_V $ is surjective is trivial.) Any closed subscheme of the affine scheme $ U $ is affine. In summary $ V $ is now a connected affine open neighborhood of $ x $ . (We've shown that the connected components of an affine Noetherian scheme must also be affine)

You know how to proceed after this, as you indicate.

Comment: Thank you! I've been actually thinking of its connected components, but I forgot to use the noetherian property to conclude that there finitely many connected components. This is the key point. Thanks for pointing it out!